# Standardize data columns in R

Tags: r, normalization

I have a dataset called `spam` which contains 58 columns and approximately 3500 rows of data related to spam messages.

I plan on running some linear regression on this dataset in the future, but I'd like to do some pre-processing beforehand and standardize the columns to have zero mean and unit variance.

I've been told the best way to go about this is with R, so I'd like to ask **how can i achieve normalization with R**? I've already got the data properly loaded and I'm just looking for some packages or methods to perform this task.

Answer (score 638, accepted):

I have to assume you meant to say that you wanted a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1.  If your data is in a dataframe and all the columns are numeric you can simply call the `scale` function on the data to do what you want.

```
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10, 30, .2), y = runif(10, 3, 5))
scaled.dat <- scale(dat)

# check that we get mean of 0 and sd of 1
colMeans(scaled.dat)  # faster version of apply(scaled.dat, 2, mean)
apply(scaled.dat, 2, sd)
```

Using built in functions is classy.  Like this cat:

[image]

Comment: Yes my mistake I meant 0 mean. And that is quite a classy cat

Comment: +1 using apply can be slow also like this fat cat:) (colMeans here)

Comment: @agstudy Fair enough.  I should get in the habit of using colMeans/colSums more.  I guess I don't think of it unless I'm in a situation where it actually matters...

Comment: If you could answer one quick question... how do I reference a range of columns from a dataframe? I want to do 

    
    scaled.spam<-scale(spam[columns 1 through 56])


Is there a decent way to do this?

Comment: this site needs more cats +1

Comment: is is possible to use scale for normalizing a matrix having NA values?

Comment: @weber85 It looks like it uses na.rm for it's center and scale calculation by default and then leaves NAs as NAs afterward. So yes you can.

Comment: so that's why I don't need to set na.rm as an argument. thanks a lot.

Comment: Warning: scale also transforms the data frame into a matrix

Comment: @JulianKarls how to avoid this problem ?

Comment: @JulianKarls I join the question. Currently I do it manually by saving the names, rewrite the matrix as data.frame and set the names correctly. If anyone wants the code, let me know.

Comment: Apparently `drop = FALSE` doesn't work here. You can however use: `as.data.frame(scale(dat))`

Comment: To get the scaled result (matrix) back as a data frame: `dat <- as.data.frame(scale(dat))`

Comment: If there are missing values in the columns we are normalizing, how should we handle that?

Comment: Thanks, if I want a mean of 100 and a standard deviation of 10?

Comment: @ahbon scale then multiply by 10 and add 100

Comment: "scale(dat)" sounds like telling R to "scale that".

Comment: If you have multiple columns to scale, you can just do `dat[c("x", "y")] <- scale(dat[c("x", "y")])`. This will keep `dat` as a data frame.

Answer (score 124):

Realizing that the question is old and one answer is accepted, I'll provide another answer for reference.

`scale` is limited by the fact that it scales **all variables**. The solution below allows to scale only specific variable names while preserving other variables unchanged (and the variable names could be dynamically generated):

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1234)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10, 30, .2), 
                  y = runif(10, 3, 5),
                  z = runif(10, 10, 20))
dat

dat2 <- dat %>% mutate_at(c("y", "z"), ~(scale(.) %>% as.vector))
dat2
```

which gives me this:

```
> dat
          x        y        z
1  29.75859 3.633225 14.56091
2  30.05549 3.605387 12.65187
3  30.21689 3.318092 13.04672
4  29.53086 3.079992 15.07307
5  30.08582 3.437599 11.81096
6  30.10121 4.621197 17.59671
7  29.88505 4.051395 12.01248
8  29.89067 4.829316 12.58810
9  29.88711 4.662690 19.92150
10 29.82199 3.091541 18.07352
```

and

```
> dat2 <- dat %>% mutate_at(c("y", "z"), ~(scale(.) %>% as.vector))
> dat2
          x          y           z
1  29.75859 -0.3004815 -0.06016029
2  30.05549 -0.3423437 -0.72529604
3  30.21689 -0.7743696 -0.58772361
4  29.53086 -1.1324181  0.11828039
5  30.08582 -0.5946582 -1.01827752
6  30.10121  1.1852038  0.99754666
7  29.88505  0.3283513 -0.94806607
8  29.89067  1.4981677 -0.74751378
9  29.88711  1.2475998  1.80753470
10 29.82199 -1.1150515  1.16367556
```

**EDIT 1 (2016)**: Addressed Julian's comment: the output of `scale` is Nx1 matrix so ideally we should add an `as.vector` to convert the matrix type back into a vector type. Thanks Julian!

**EDIT 2 (2019)**: Quoting Duccio A.'s comment: For the latest dplyr (version 0.8) you need to change dplyr::funcs with list, like `dat %>% mutate_each_(list(~scale(.) %>% as.vector), vars=c("y","z"))`

**EDIT 3 (2020)**: Thanks to @mj_whales: the old solution is deprecated and now we need to use `mutate_at`.

Comment: This method works perfectly, specially when I have combination of categorical and numerical variables. I just have one question what does this operator means "%>%"?

Comment: @weber85, it is a "pipe" operator (from functional programming). Instead of writing `f(g(x))` it would look nicer if one writes `x %>% g %>% f`. In other words, `dat %>% mutate_each_(funs(scale),vars=c("y","z"))` is just `mutate_each_(dat,funs(scale),vars=c("y","z"))`. The operator helps a lot when a chain is very long since `f(g(h(i(j(x)))))` can be very hard to read.

Comment: Using this approach the columns on which scale is applied to are transferred from vector (class numeric) to Nx1 matrices. This might (and in my case did) cause some errors in packages that assume each column of a data.frame is a vector.

Comment: @JulianKarls, thanks! You are correct. I added `as.vector` to the answer in order to convert an Nx1 matrix into a vector for cases like yours.

Comment: the dplyr code does not work any more with the newest version

Comment: How do you then convert the scaled data back to its original form?

Comment: For the latest `dplyr` (version 0.8) you need to change `dplyr::funcs` with `list`, like `dat %>% mutate_each_(list(~scale(.) %>% as.vector), vars=c("y","z"))`

Comment: `mutate_each_()` is now deprecated. You can use `mutate_at()` instead. The new way to do it would be: `dat2 <- dat %>% mutate_at(c("y", "z"), scale)`

Comment: `dplyr` landscape is shifting yet again. In `dplyr 1.0.0` (in development) `mutate(across(x:y, scale))` appears to be the correct solution now.

Comment: ... or you could just do `dat[columns] <- scale(dat[columns])`, which has worked consistently for the past 20 years ;-)

Comment: @dash2 Very true! Though I do like my pipes :)

Comment: I think the latest way is to use accross as in mutate(accross(all_of(c("y", "z")),scale))

Comment: `data %>% mutate(across(all_of(c("y", "z")), scale))`

Answer (score 74):

This is 3 years old. Still, I feel I have to add the following:

The most common normalization is the *z-transformation*, where you subtract the mean and divide by the standard deviation of your variable. The result will have mean=0 and sd=1.

For that, you don't need any package.

```
zVar <- (myVar - mean(myVar)) / sd(myVar)
```

That's it.

Comment: Totally a simple way to perform this. Thanks

Comment: And makes using it dplyr much easier: `mutate(var = (var - mean(var))/sd(var))`.

Comment: But can this be used to get the z-score for two variables?

Comment: to denormalize `myVar <- (zVar * sd(zVar)) + mean(zVar)`, right?

Comment: @Artur_Indio Almost: `newVar <- (zVar * sd(myVar)) + mean(myVar)`.  You have to use the original mean/sd.  As you wrote it, you'll multiply by `sd(zVar)=1` and add `mean(zVar)=0`, so nothing will change :)

Answer (score 28):

'Caret' package provides methods for preprocessing data (e.g. centering and scaling). You could also use the following code:

```
library(caret)
# Assuming goal class is column 10
preObj <- preProcess(data[, -10], method=c("center", "scale"))
newData <- predict(preObj, data[, -10])
```

More details: http://www.inside-r.org/node/86978

Answer (score 25):

When I used the solution stated by Dason, instead of getting a data frame as a result, I got a vector of numbers (the scaled values of my df).

In case someone is having the same trouble, you have to add as.data.frame() to the code, like this:

```
df.scaled <- as.data.frame(scale(df))
```

I hope this is will be useful for ppl having the same issue!

Comment: Nice solution! In case someone wants to exclude a column from been scaled you can do it like this:

```train_dt[-24] <- scale(train_dt[-24])```




where "24" is the column number to be excluded

Answer (score 20):

You can easily normalize the data also using data.Normalization function in clusterSim package. It provides different method of data normalization.

```
    data.Normalization (x,type="n0",normalization="column")
```

Arguments

x
vector, matrix or dataset
type
type of normalization:
n0 - without normalization

n1 - standardization ((x-mean)/sd)

n2 - positional standardization ((x-median)/mad)

n3 - unitization ((x-mean)/range)

n3a - positional unitization ((x-median)/range)

n4 - unitization with zero minimum ((x-min)/range)

n5 - normalization in range <-1,1> ((x-mean)/max(abs(x-mean)))

n5a - positional normalization in range <-1,1> ((x-median)/max(abs(x-median)))

n6 - quotient transformation (x/sd)

n6a - positional quotient transformation (x/mad)

n7 - quotient transformation (x/range)

n8 - quotient transformation (x/max)

n9 - quotient transformation (x/mean)

n9a - positional quotient transformation (x/median)

n10 - quotient transformation (x/sum)

n11 - quotient transformation (x/sqrt(SSQ))

n12 - normalization ((x-mean)/sqrt(sum((x-mean)^2)))

n12a - positional normalization ((x-median)/sqrt(sum((x-median)^2)))

n13 - normalization with zero being the central point ((x-midrange)/(range/2))

normalization
"column" - normalization by variable, "row" - normalization by object

Comment: this package is not available for R version 3.4.3

Answer (score 18):

With `dplyr` v0.7.4 all variables can be scaled by using `mutate_all()`:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tibble)

set.seed(1234)
dat <- tibble(x = rnorm(10, 30, .2), 
              y = runif(10, 3, 5),
              z = runif(10, 10, 20))

dat %>% mutate_all(scale)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>         x      y       z
#>     <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 -0.827 -0.300 -0.0602
#>  2  0.663 -0.342 -0.725 
#>  3  1.47  -0.774 -0.588 
#>  4 -1.97  -1.13   0.118 
#>  5  0.816 -0.595 -1.02  
#>  6  0.893  1.19   0.998 
#>  7 -0.192  0.328 -0.948 
#>  8 -0.164  1.50  -0.748 
#>  9 -0.182  1.25   1.81  
#> 10 -0.509 -1.12   1.16
```

Specific variables can be excluded using `mutate_at()`:

```r
dat %>% mutate_at(scale, .vars = vars(-x))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>        x      y       z
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1  29.8 -0.300 -0.0602
#>  2  30.1 -0.342 -0.725 
#>  3  30.2 -0.774 -0.588 
#>  4  29.5 -1.13   0.118 
#>  5  30.1 -0.595 -1.02  
#>  6  30.1  1.19   0.998 
#>  7  29.9  0.328 -0.948 
#>  8  29.9  1.50  -0.748 
#>  9  29.9  1.25   1.81  
#> 10  29.8 -1.12   1.16
```

Created on 2018-04-24 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 11):

Again, even though this is an old question, it is very relevant! And I have found a simple way to normalise certain columns without the need of any packages:

```
normFunc <- function(x){(x-mean(x, na.rm = T))/sd(x, na.rm = T)}
```

For example

```
x<-rnorm(10,14,2)
y<-rnorm(10,7,3)
z<-rnorm(10,18,5)
df<-data.frame(x,y,z)

df[2:3] <- apply(df[2:3], 2, normFunc)
```

You will see that the y and z columns have been normalised. No packages needed :-)

Answer (score 9):

Scale can be used for both full data frame and specific columns.
For specific columns, following code can be used:

```
trainingSet[, 3:7] = scale(trainingSet[, 3:7]) # For column 3 to 7
trainingSet[, 8] = scale(trainingSet[, 8]) # For column 8
```

Full data frame

```
trainingSet <- scale(trainingSet)
```

Answer (score 4):

The *collapse* package provides the fastest scale function - implemented in C++ using Welfords Online Algorithm:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1e6, 30, .2), 
                  y = runif(1e6, 3, 5),
                  z = runif(1e6, 10, 20))

library(collapse)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fscale(dat), scale(dat))

Unit: milliseconds
        expr       min       lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
 fscale(dat)  27.86456  29.5864  38.96896  30.80421  43.79045 313.5729   100  a 
  scale(dat) 357.07130 391.0914 489.93546 416.33626 625.38561 793.2243   100   b
```

Furthermore: `fscale` is S3 generic for vectors, matrices and data frames and also supports grouped and/or weighted scaling operations, as well as scaling to arbitrary means and standard deviations.

Answer (score 2):

The `dplyr` package has two functions that do this.

```
> require(dplyr)
```

To mutate *specific* columns of a data table, you can use the function `mutate_at()`. To mutate *all* columns, you can use `mutate_all`.

The following is a brief example for using these functions to standardize data.

**Mutate specific columns:**

```
dt = data.table(a = runif(3500), b = runif(3500), c = runif(3500))
dt = data.table(dt %>% mutate_at(vars("a", "c"), scale)) # can also index columns by number, e.g., vars(c(1,3))

> apply(dt, 2, mean)
            a             b             c 
 1.783137e-16  5.064855e-01 -5.245395e-17 

> apply(dt, 2, sd)
        a         b         c 
1.0000000 0.2906622 1.0000000
```

**Mutate all columns:**

```
dt = data.table(a = runif(3500), b = runif(3500), c = runif(3500))
dt = data.table(dt %>% mutate_all(scale))

> apply(dt, 2, mean)
            a             b             c 
-1.728266e-16  9.291994e-17  1.683551e-16 

> apply(dt, 2, sd)
a b c 
1 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Before I happened to find this thread, I had the same problem. I had user dependant column types, so I wrote a `for` loop going through them and getting needed columns `scale`'d. There are probably better ways to do it, but this solved the problem just fine:

```
 for(i in 1:length(colnames(df))) {
        if(class(df[,i]) == "numeric" || class(df[,i]) == "integer") {
            df[,i] <- as.vector(scale(df[,i])) }
        }
```

`as.vector` is a needed part, because it turned out `scale` does `rownames x 1` matrix which is usually not what you want to have in your `data.frame`.

Answer (score 1):

@BBKim pretty much gave the best answer, but it can just be done shorter. I'm surprised noone came up with it yet.

`dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10, 30, .2), y = runif(10, 3, 5))
dat <- apply(dat, 2,  function(x) (x - mean(x)) / sd(x))`

Answer (score 0):

Use the package "recommenderlab". Download and install the package.
This package has a command "Normalize" in built. It also allows you to choose one of the many methods for normalization namely 'center' or 'Z-score'
Follow the following example:

```
## create a matrix with ratings
m <- matrix(sample(c(NA,0:5),50, replace=TRUE, prob=c(.5,rep(.5/6,6))),nrow=5, ncol=10, dimnames = list(users=paste('u', 1:5, sep=&rdquo;), items=paste('i', 1:10, sep=&rdquo;)))

## do normalization
r <- as(m, "realRatingMatrix")
#here, 'centre' is the default method
r_n1 <- normalize(r) 
#here "Z-score" is the used method used
r_n2 <- normalize(r, method="Z-score")

r
r_n1
r_n2

## show normalized data
image(r, main="Raw Data")
image(r_n1, main="Centered")
image(r_n2, main="Z-Score Normalization")
```

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question.

Answer (score 0):

The code below could be the shortest way to achieve this.

```
dataframe <- apply(dataframe, 2, scale)
```

Answer (score -1):

The [normalize](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/BBmisc/versions/1.10/topics/normalize) function from the BBMisc package was the right tool for me since it can deal with NA values.

Here is how to use it:

Given the following dataset,

```
    ASR_API     <- c("CV",  "F",    "IER",  "LS-c", "LS-o")
    Human       <- c(NA,    5.8,    12.7,   NA, NA)
    Google      <- c(23.2,  24.2,   16.6,   12.1,   28.8)
    GoogleCloud <- c(23.3,  26.3,   18.3,   12.3,   27.3)
    IBM     <- c(21.8,  47.6,   24.0,   9.8,    25.3)
    Microsoft   <- c(29.1,  28.1,   23.1,   18.8,   35.9)
    Speechmatics    <- c(19.1,  38.4,   21.4,   7.3,    19.4)
    Wit_ai      <- c(35.6,  54.2,   37.4,   19.2,   41.7)
    dt     <- data.table(ASR_API,Human, Google, GoogleCloud, IBM, Microsoft, Speechmatics, Wit_ai)
> dt
   ASR_API Human Google GoogleCloud  IBM Microsoft Speechmatics Wit_ai
1:      CV    NA   23.2        23.3 21.8      29.1         19.1   35.6
2:       F   5.8   24.2        26.3 47.6      28.1         38.4   54.2
3:     IER  12.7   16.6        18.3 24.0      23.1         21.4   37.4
4:    LS-c    NA   12.1        12.3  9.8      18.8          7.3   19.2
5:    LS-o    NA   28.8        27.3 25.3      35.9         19.4   41.7
```

normalized values can be obtained like this:

```
> dtn <- normalize(dt, method = "standardize", range = c(0, 1), margin = 1L, on.constant = "quiet")
> dtn
   ASR_API      Human     Google GoogleCloud         IBM  Microsoft Speechmatics      Wit_ai
1:      CV         NA  0.3361245   0.2893457 -0.28468670  0.3247336  -0.18127203 -0.16032655
2:       F -0.7071068  0.4875320   0.7715885  1.59862532  0.1700986   1.55068347  1.31594762
3:     IER  0.7071068 -0.6631646  -0.5143923 -0.12409420 -0.6030768   0.02512682 -0.01746131
4:    LS-c         NA -1.3444981  -1.4788780 -1.16064578 -1.2680075  -1.24018782 -1.46198764
5:    LS-o         NA  1.1840062   0.9323361 -0.02919864  1.3762521  -0.15435044  0.32382788
```

where hand calculated method just ignores colmuns containing NAs:

```
> dt %>% mutate(normalizedHuman = (Human - mean(Human))/sd(Human)) %>% 
+ mutate(normalizedGoogle = (Google - mean(Google))/sd(Google)) %>% 
+ mutate(normalizedGoogleCloud = (GoogleCloud - mean(GoogleCloud))/sd(GoogleCloud)) %>% 
+ mutate(normalizedIBM = (IBM - mean(IBM))/sd(IBM)) %>% 
+ mutate(normalizedMicrosoft = (Microsoft - mean(Microsoft))/sd(Microsoft)) %>% 
+ mutate(normalizedSpeechmatics = (Speechmatics - mean(Speechmatics))/sd(Speechmatics)) %>% 
+ mutate(normalizedWit_ai = (Wit_ai - mean(Wit_ai))/sd(Wit_ai))
  ASR_API Human Google GoogleCloud  IBM Microsoft Speechmatics Wit_ai normalizedHuman normalizedGoogle
1      CV    NA   23.2        23.3 21.8      29.1         19.1   35.6              NA        0.3361245
2       F   5.8   24.2        26.3 47.6      28.1         38.4   54.2              NA        0.4875320
3     IER  12.7   16.6        18.3 24.0      23.1         21.4   37.4              NA       -0.6631646
4    LS-c    NA   12.1        12.3  9.8      18.8          7.3   19.2              NA       -1.3444981
5    LS-o    NA   28.8        27.3 25.3      35.9         19.4   41.7              NA        1.1840062
  normalizedGoogleCloud normalizedIBM normalizedMicrosoft normalizedSpeechmatics normalizedWit_ai
1             0.2893457   -0.28468670           0.3247336            -0.18127203      -0.16032655
2             0.7715885    1.59862532           0.1700986             1.55068347       1.31594762
3            -0.5143923   -0.12409420          -0.6030768             0.02512682      -0.01746131
4            -1.4788780   -1.16064578          -1.2680075            -1.24018782      -1.46198764
5             0.9323361   -0.02919864           1.3762521            -0.15435044       0.32382788
```

(normalizedHuman is made a list of NAs ...)

regarding the selection of specific columns for calculation, a generic method can be employed like this one:

```
data_vars <- df_full %>% dplyr::select(-ASR_API,-otherVarNotToBeUsed)
meta_vars <- df_full %>% dplyr::select(ASR_API,otherVarNotToBeUsed)
data_varsn <- normalize(data_vars, method = "standardize", range = c(0, 1), margin = 1L, on.constant = "quiet")
dtn <- cbind(meta_vars,data_varsn)
```