# Normalizing data with a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 0.5 in R

Tags: r, dataset

I have a data set I am trying to normalize with a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 0.5.

[Standardize data columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215457/standardize-data-columns-in-r)

This question seemed to be similar to my needs but I am not sure how to change the standard deviation from 1 to 0.5.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 6):

If you have a Normal(0,sd=1) distribution and you want a Normal(0,sd=.5), just multiply by .5. See

```
# x ~ Normal(0,1)
x<-rnorm(10000)
mean(x)
# [1] 0.003044746
sd(x)
# [1] 0.9987472

#transform
y <- .5*x
mean(y)
# [1] 0.001522373
sd(y)
# [1] 0.4993736
```

Comment: Also note that this really has nothing to do with the normal distribution and this advice holds for any distribution with a finite standard deviation.