# How to exlude NA values in a column when performing z-normalization

Tags: r, dplyr, normalization, missing-data

I need to do a z-normalization on my data (i.e transform variables to mean=0 and sd=1).

I am using the following formula (e.g. scaling mean annual temperature, "MAT"):

```
sca$MAT <- (sca$MAT - mean(sca$MAT)) / sd(sca$MAT)
```

But I get NaN values since few data are missing for this variable. How can I exlude NA values for MAT in the above formula?

PS: I tried to include `na.rm=TRUE` in the formula but it doesn't work.

A faster way could probably use `dplyr` as showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215457/standardize-data-columns-in-r): but I get the same problem

Comment: Did you use `na.rm=T` in both `mean` and `sd` calls? Then you should only get NAs for those values that were NA originally, others should scale correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A fast solution is to use the *is.na* function in order to obtain the index of the NA elements and then to remove them. The commands are the following:

`clean <- sca$MAT[-is.na(sca$MAT)]
standardized <- (clean - mean(clean)) / sd(clean)`

Answer (score 0):

`scale` will exclude NAs for you

```
x <- c(1:5,NA)
scale(x)
           [,1]
[1,] -1.2649111
[2,] -0.6324555
[3,]  0.0000000
[4,]  0.6324555
[5,]  1.2649111
[6,]         NA
attr(,"scaled:center")
[1] 3
attr(,"scaled:scale")
[1] 1.581139
```

so `sca$MAT <- scale(sca$MAT)` should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Using `na.rm=TRUE` should work

For example:

```
> sca <- data.frame(L=LETTERS[1:6], MAT=c(1:5,NA))
> sca
  L MAT
1 A   1
2 B   2
3 C   3
4 D   4
5 E   5
6 F  NA
> sca$MAT <- (sca$MAT - mean(sca$MAT, na.rm=TRUE)) / sd(sca$MAT, na.rm=TRUE)
> sca
  L        MAT
1 A -1.2649111
2 B -0.6324555
3 C  0.0000000
4 D  0.6324555
5 E  1.2649111
6 F         NA
```

gives the same results as Glen_b's use of `scale`