# scale variables in dataframe using another dataframe

Tags: r, standardized

I have a dataframe with following variables

```
dat <- data.frame(cell.ID = 1:10, cell.name = letters[1:10], 
              groupID = rep(1:2, each = 5), 
              x1 = rnorm(10), x2 = rnorm(10), 
              x3 = rnorm(10), x4= rnorm(10), 
              x5 = rnorm(10), x6 = rnorm(10))
```

I have a mean and sd stored to normalise x1 to x6 in another dataframe

```
norm_fin <- data.frame(variable = paste0('x',1:6), 
                   meanVar = rnorm(6),
                   SdVar = rnorm(6))
```

I want to create a new dataframe from `dat` after normalised x1 to x6. I did a loop solution

```
 varVec <- paste0('x',1:6)
 dat1 <- dat
 for(i in varVec){
  meanRef <- norm_fin$meanVar[norm_fin$variable == i]
  sdRef <- norm_fin$SdVar[norm_fin$variable == i]
  dat1[, i] <- (dat[, i] - meanRef)/sdRef
}
```

Is there another solution without using a loop?

Comment: I am a bit confused what exactly you try to do. Why do you store the mean and sd? Why wouldn't an inbuild function like scale do the work? Or why not just calculating the mean (or sd) of the variable in your mutation? Like they do here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215457/standardize-data-columns-in-r

Comment: the mean and sd were derived from a different dataset of x1 to x6 and I want to use those mean and sd to normalise the new x1 to x6 in the new data `dat`

Comment: Why not simply join it so it is in the same row and than use mutate? Edit: oh well I see that is someone else's answer indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert the data into long format and then left join `norm_find`, calculate the value and then get the data back in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('x')) %>%
  left_join(norm_fin, by = c('name' = 'variable')) %>%
  mutate(val = (value - meanVar)/SdVar) %>%
  select(-value, -meanVar, -SdVar) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = val)

# A tibble: 10 x 9
#   cell.ID cell.name groupID     x1      x2     x3    x4     x5      x6
#     <int> <fct>       <int>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1       1 a               1 -2.10   32.6   -0.797 0.705 -0.768  0.0217
# 2       2 b               1 -1.36   16.3    0.125 0.353 -1.76   0.144 
# 3       3 c               1  2.63   17.0   -0.751 0.933  0.394  0.150 
# 4       4 d               1 -0.690  11.6   -0.429 0.925 -6.60  -0.461 
# 5       5 e               1 -0.559  -1.01  -0.316 0.898 -4.64   0.229 
# 6       6 f               2  2.98   43.2   -1.47  0.833  0.105 -0.525 
# 7       7 g               2  0.181  18.9    1.27  0.767 -1.36   0.802 
# 8       8 h               2 -3.67  -27.6    0.528 0.467 -1.23  -0.122 
# 9       9 i               2 -2.38   22.7   -0.873 0.348 -3.77   0.0778
#10      10 j               2 -1.84    0.557  1.72  0.311 -2.01   0.0379
```

**data**

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(cell.ID = 1:10, cell.name = letters[1:10], 
                  groupID = rep(1:2, each = 5), 
                  x1 = rnorm(10), x2 = rnorm(10), 
                  x3 = rnorm(10), x4= rnorm(10), 
                  x5 = rnorm(10), x6 = rnorm(10))

norm_fin <- data.frame(variable = paste0('x',1:6), 
                       meanVar = rnorm(6),
                       SdVar = rnorm(6))
```